# How to convert object to int[]?

Tags: c#

Simple question. I have a TempData which I use to store temporarily an int array. I pass this to another action result. Then I just need to convert it to an int array. Can anyone help?

Action Result:

```
public ActionResult SupplierReportSelection(
    int ClientID, int[] ReviewPeriodID, int? GroupID, int? SupplierID = null, 
    bool? Backbtn = null, int? StatusCategoryID = null) 
{
    if (TempData["TempReviewPeriod"] != null) {
        var convertToString = TempData["TempReviewPeriod"].ToString();
    }

    // Removed unnecessary code

    return View("ClaimsBySupplier");
}
```

Comment: What? Please be clear.... What's your problem inside the code. I can see `var convert`, ...

Comment: you mean `int[] temp  = (int[])TempData["TempReviewPeriod"];`?

Comment: have you tried with `TempData["TempReviewPeriod"] as int[]`  or `(int[])TempData["TempReviewPeriod"]` ?

Comment: Can you show the code where you store the `int[]` into the `TempData["TempReviewPeriod"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

`int[] temp = (int[])TempData["TempReviewPeriod"];`

For a bit more background on this:

TempData whose underlying type (`TempDataDictionary`) implements `IDictionary<string, object>`:

`public class TempDataDictionary : IDictionary<string, object>`

Accessing the dictionary by `key` returns `object` - so from that point onwards, you can cast to the required type.

Comment: Thanks Ric! I didn't know you could cast an array, I thought you could only cast simple data types!

Comment: You can cast to pretty much any object type you want

Comment: granted that said object is indeed of the right type

Comment: of course, there is always the `as` syntax to check the type can be carried out first ;)